# Problems deploying Vue project after build on Apache webserver due to wrong relative paths

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yarnpkg

I have a simple Vue.js project. I ran the command `yarn build`, then copied all the files inside dist/ folder onto Apache webserver.

When my URL pointed to the generated index.html, nothing appeared. I discovered this was due index.html pointing to the wrong relative paths that contain the js and CSS files.

For example, I noticed this wrong relative inside index.html
`<script type=module src=/js/app.4dcb0a0b.js></script>`
The correct one should be
`<script type=module src=./js/app.4dcb0a0b.js></script>`
It should be `./js` and not `/js`.

After I corrected the relative paths, index.html appear correctly.

It is tedious if I have to manually change the wrong relative paths every time. How can I have a better solution?

I am using @vue/cli 5.0.1, yarn v1.22.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

Credit for the answer goes to this article

https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-solve-vue-js-prod-build-assets-relative-path-problem-71f91138dd79

Solution is to add the following line to vue.config.js;

```
module.exports = {publicPath: ''};
```

I do not know why this solution works. If someone knows, please drop some comments. Thank you.